# Property of little o notation $f(x) o (g(x)) = o(f(x)g(x))$

Tags: calculus

This question is regarding property of little o notation given in Apostol Calculus. The property is given on page 288 and stated as:

> Theorem 7.8 (c) As $x\to a$ we have $f(x)\cdot o (g(x)) = o(f(x)g(x))$.

Here say $h(x) = o(g(x))$ then we have $f(x) \lim_{x\to a} \frac{h(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, and on the right, we have $j(x) = o(f(x)g(x)) $ then $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{j(x)}{f(x)g(x)} = 0$ .. I am confused to approach the proof.

Comment: what is the mean of $f(x)o(g(x))$? product?

Comment: @martin oh yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition

$$f(x) o (g(x)) = f(x)\cdot \omega(x)g(x)$$

with

$$\omega(x)\to 0 \quad x\to a$$

therefore

$$f(x) o (g(x)) = \omega(x)\cdot f(x)g(x)=o(f(x)g(x))$$

Comment: Thanks it was so easy :)

Comment: @jeea Yes indeed we need just to apply te definition!

Comment: @gimusi: I don't think that the stated definition is sound. The left hand side represents a set of functions while the right hand side does not. Usually this is the other way round as we can see e.g. with $h(x)$ in the post of jeea.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer The definition I know is that $f(x)=o(g(x)) \iff f(x)=\omega(x)\cdot g(x)$ with $\omega(x)\to 0$.

Comment: @gimusi: I agree. *This* definition is sound contrary to that stated in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$o(g(x))=g(x)\epsilon(x)$$ with $$\lim_{x\to a}\epsilon(x)=0$$

then

$$f(x)o(g(x))=\Bigl(f(x)g(x)\Bigr)\epsilon(x)=o(f(x)g(x))$$

Comment: Thanks you too!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based upon Apostol's settings. First of all we should be aware that the equality  sign $=$ here is used to indicate a subset relation $\subseteq$ between two sets 
\begin{align*}
f(x)o(g(x))=o(f(x)g(x)\qquad\qquad \text{as }x\to a
\end{align*}
meaning that whenever a function  $h=h(x)$ is an element of  the left-hand  side $f(x)o(g(x))$ it is  also  an element  of  the right-hand  side $o(f(x)g(x))$ as $x\to a$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{h(x)}&\color{blue}{=f(x)o(g(x))\qquad\text{as }x\to a}\\
> &\quad:\Longleftrightarrow\ \exists h_1: h(x)=f(x)h_1(x)\quad\text{ and }\quad\lim_{x\to a}\frac{h_1(x)}{g(x)}=0\\
> &\quad\ \ \Longrightarrow\ \exists h_1: h(x)=f(x)h_1(x)\quad\text{ and }\quad\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)h_1(x)}{f(x)g(x)}=0\\
> &\quad\ \ \Longrightarrow\ \ \color{blue}{h(x)=o(f(x)g(x))\qquad \text{as }x\to a}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.