# $h(x) = o(f(x)g(x)) \implies h(x) = f(x) \cdot o(g(x))$?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Let's define $o(g(x))$ as usually:

$$
\forall x \ne a.g(x) \ne 0 \\
f(x) = o(g(x)) \space \text{when} \space x \to a \implies \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0
$$

Is it true that: $h(x) = o(f(x)g(x)) \implies h(x) = f(x) \cdot o(g(x))$?

The way I would approach proving that is as follows:

$$
h(x) = o(f(x)g(x)) \text{ when $x \to a$ } \implies \lim_{x \to a} \frac{h(x)}{f(x)g(x)} = 0 \implies \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}}{g(x)} = 0  \\
\implies \frac{h(x)}{f(x)} = o(g(x)) \implies h(x) = f(x) \cdot o(g(x))
$$

I know the implication in the other way holds ([question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828472/property-of-little-o-notation-fx-o-gx-ofxgx)), but I'm not sure if it is bidirectional (if the two right hand-sides are equivalent). For example, if $h(x) = o(x) \implies h(x) = x \cdot o(1)$, the right hand-side of the right side of the implication is defined at $x = 0$, while the right hand side of the left side of the implication is not. That would confuse me if that equivalence of the two sides holds because we should completely ignore the point $0$ when analysing that?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use the definition with $ \eps(x) $, things will be Easier for you. !

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Thank you for the suggestion, but it seems like I'm almost done with getting the basic understanding of what Tom Apostol had in mind, and I'll move on soon hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a disclaimer: your notation is incorrect.

$o(f)$ is not a **function**, it is a **family of functions**. In particular, $F\in o(f)$ is true if and only if $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{F(x)}{f(x)}$$ is true.

With that, you may notice that the notation $h(x)=o(f(x)g(x))$ is a little strange, because you have what you want is a function on the left, but a set on the right. So it would be better to phrase your question as

> If $h\in o(f\cdot g)$, does that mean that $h=f\cdot G$ for some $G\in o(g)$?

and this is the question I will address from no on.

---

The answer is yes.

You can first write $h(x)=f(x)\cdot G(x)$ where

$$G(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{h(x)}{f(x)};&f(x)\neq 0\\
0;&f(x)=0\end{cases}$$

now all you need to do is prove that $G\in o(g)$. This is true because

$$\frac{G(x)}{g(x)} = \begin{cases}\frac{h(x)}{f(x)g(x)};&f(x)\neq 0\\ 0;&f(x)=0\end{cases}.$$

which means that it should be easy to see, for example from the sandwich theorem or just by definition of limit, that $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{G(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$

Comment: In the theory of asymptotic expansions, the notation $f(x)=o(g(x))$ is standard.

Comment: Thank you 5xum, but, as Gary mentioned, I don't see anything wrong with the notation I'm using (Tom Apostol uses the same notation like me, and someone would point out that mistake in the last 50 years if it was wrong (rather than just an accepted notation abuse)). Could your answer be made valid, without introducing a different definition of $o$?

Comment: @S11n My answer is valid even with your definition of $o$. Just replace any $g\in o(f)$ with "$g(x)=o(f(x))$" and you are done. And sure, I was a little rough by saying "wrong", it is, as you say, just "notation abuse". But given that your question shows you are still a beginner in the field, I think it is safer to stick to more rigid notation. Shortcuts are very useful once you know what they are covering up. Before that, they are, in my opinion, extremely dangerous and detrimental to learning.

Comment: @S11n Also, even with your notation, you still need to do some work on your original answer, because even in the abused notation, saying $$\frac{h(x)}{f(x)} =o(g(x))$$ is simply not true in all cases. For example, if $f$ is the zero function, then the above expression bexomes meaningless, even if $h(x)=f(x)\cdot o(g(x))$ is still true.

Comment: @5xum Your last sentence in your last comment was why I was not happy with my answer. I was missing the connection that the implication in the $o$ notation can be seen as iff (i.e. bidirectional, like you did in your answer). Thanks!